# Apache Commons Configuration trigger event on property file change

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

I'm using Apache Commons Configuration library to store my app properties. 
I can monitor changes of property file using `FileChangedReloadingStrategy` and it works perfectly. 
What I would like to do is to trigger `configurationChanged` event of `ConfigurationListener` when property file is changed.

This case works if I will try to get a property from my code

```
directory = MyConfiguration.getInstance().getString("directory");
```

this line will trigger `configurationChanged`. But I need this event to be triggered when `FileChangedReloadingStrategy` catches changes in file without doing redundant calls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FileChangedReloadingStrategy works by checking the file modification time every time you read a parameter. If you don't read the anything, Apache configuration code is not invoked so there is no way to send notification to you.

For my app, this is more desirable because I don't care about the file change until I need to use it.

You can write a new strategy to accomplish what you want. You need to start a new thread and monitor the file periodically.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually I just needed to add a timer task which will just fetch a property from configuration file, this action will automatically trigger FileChangedReloadingStrategy+ConfigurationListener.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous poster mentioned, you could roll your own strategy. For monitoring changes to the file, you can use [JPoller](http://jpoller.sourceforge.net/).